# Здравствуйте помогите пожалуйста input type range

Tags: javascript

Есть два input type range/ При передвигание одного ползунка, срабатывает второй тоесть повторяет такие же движение. К примеру первый ползунок идет в слева на право, второй делает то же самое. Спасибо заранее

Comment: Код лучше покажи...Не гадать же что да как реализованно...

Comment: А вопрос в чем?

Comment: Нажми кнопку под вопросом `править` и выложи код

Comment: Все спасибо всем ниже представлен пример который был нужен. Извините я впервые пользуюсь стэком.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Событие `input` в помощь

```js
var range1 = document.getElementById('range1');
var range2 = document.getElementById('range2');

range1.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  range2.value = e.target.value;
});
range2.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  range1.value = e.target.value;
});
```

```html
<input type="range" id="range1">
<input type="range" id="range2">
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать jQuery

```
<input type="range" id="range-1">
<input type="range" id="range-2">

<script>
  // Подписываемся на событие изменения первого инпута
  $('#range-1').change(function() {
    // При срабатывании, записываем значение первого во второй
    $('#range-2').val($(this).val());
  })
</script>
```

Возможно второй ползунок изменится только после того как движение первого будет окончено, тогда нужно будет реализовывать через mousemove